# Problem with validation of schema in python

Tags: python

For my script, I need to check if some object is a list of dictionnaries or a list of list of dictionnaries in order to perform corresponding actions, or else raise an error.

To be more specific, the following should be accepted (with two different conditions):

```
mylist = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3},{'d': 4}]
mylist1 = [[{'a':1}, {'ccc':4}], [{'e': 3}]]
```

but, for instance, the following should raise an error:

```
c = [[]]
d = [[{'a':1}], {'b':2}]
```

I have implemented a naive solution as follows:

```
if set([type(x) for x in mylist]) == set([dict]):
    print('first case')
elif set([type(x) for x in mylist]) == set([list]) and set([type(x) for y in mylist for x in y ])== set([dict]):
    print('second case')
else:
    raise Exception('wrong structure')
```

I tried using a schema validation but I do not seem to get how to do that.
Any help to make this more readable / elegant would be appreciated!!

Thanking you in advance,

M

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/45812387/7349206

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The problem is that I need to be more general that that : I do not know the keys, nor the number of elements in my structure..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that `type(dict)` evaluates as `type` as `dict` is already type designation.

So, you would need to change `if set([type(x) for x in mylist]) == set([type(dict)])` to `if set([type(x) for x in mylist]) == set([dict])`

Also, it's not very good idea to throw general `Exception`, you can, e.g. use `TypeError` for this type of Exception

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the question. In my script I had written type(dict()) and type(list()) which does evaluate types as wanted. The problem persist on how to write in a more general / elegant / readable way..