# Restrict adding bad entry to python dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

We have sample Python dictionary as given below, which can be modify by multiple developers in our project.
What could be best way to avoid developers not to add other than given sample keys, also to avoid them to add incorrect zip entry in address of person( zip should validate through post codes then allow to add zip), etc. also there is no currency exists with 'AAA' its invalid key, also having invalid value, I think we can do it with special functions dict.**add** dict.**key** is there any other best way to do it.

```
 people = {1: {'name': 'John', 'age': '27', 'sex': 'Male', 'Address': { 'Door': '9-8-11', 'street': 'John-street', 'city': 'NewYork', 'zip':'99705'}, 'ExchangeCurrency':{'USD':'INR'}},
          2: {'name': 'Marie', 'age': '22', 'sex': 'Female', 'Address': { 'Door': '9-8-11', 'street': 'John-street', 'city': 'NewYork', 'zip': '99705'}, 'ExchangeCurrency':{'INR':'EUR'}}}
```

Eg of bad entry:

```
{1: {'name12': 'John', 'age': '27', 'sex': 'Male', 'Address': { 'Door': '9-8-11', 'street': 'John-street', 'city': 'NewYork', 'zip':'000000'}, 'ExchangeCurrency':{'AAA':'CCC'}}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812387/how-to-validate-structure-or-schema-of-dictionary-in-python#45812483

Comment: What do you mean with modify? Do they typically access the definition of the dictionary or do they modify it from elsewhere with index access and so on?

Comment: Yes they access the defination of the dictionary, I wan to restrict them not to add invalid either key or value while doing it.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that you might want to consider is creating your own class for each of the people for which the "given sample keys" (e.g. name, age, sex, and address) are object attributes and keyword arguments to the initialization function. For instance, you could do the following.

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name = '', age = '0', sex = None, address = {}):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.sex = sex
        self.address = address
```

With that, you can enter person one into the system with

```
person_1 = Person(name = 'John', 
                  age = '27', 
                  sex = 'Male', 
                  address = { 'Door': '9-8-11', 'street': 'John-street', 'city': 'NewYork', 'zip':'99705'})
```

In fact, you can very nicely unpack your dictionary version of a person to create this a `Person` instance. For example, we can change your dictionary of dictionaries to a dictionary of `Person` objects as follows.

```
people_dic_1 = {1: {'name': 'John', 'age': '27', 'sex': 'Male', 'address': { 'door': '9-8-11', 'street': 'John-street', 'city': 'NewYork', 'zip':'99705'}},
                2: {'name': 'Marie', 'age': '22', 'sex': 'Female', 'address': { 'door': '9-8-11', 'street': 'John-street', 'city': 'NewYork', 'zip': '99705'}}}
people_dic_2 = {k:Person(**v) for k,v in people_dic.items()}
```

In the above, `Person(**v)` is a person object with attributes determined by the dictionary `v`. Notably, calling `Person(**v)` will only work if each key corresponds to a (correctly named) keyword argument of the `__init__` method.

To go the other direction, you can call `vars` on a `Person` object to produce the kind of dictionary that you've been using. For instance, calling `vars(people_dic_2[2])` after running the above code yields the dictionary

```
{'name': 'Marie',
 'age': '22',
 'sex': 'Female',
 'address': {'door': '9-8-11',
  'street': 'John-street',
  'city': 'NewYork',
  'zip': '99705'}}
```

You could similarly create a class for addresses, if you're so inclined.