# Using dynamic object name in YAML scheme

Tags: python, validation, yaml

I want to validate YAML files in Python with my own scheme.
A valid YAML shall look like this:

```
input:
  - name1
split_to:
  windows:
    - split1
  other:
    - split2
```

While [windows, other] are dynamic, any name shall allowed there (i.e. "solaris", "mac", "templeOS")

I'm using **validate** from **jsonschema** like described here: [Validating a yaml document in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262569/validating-a-yaml-document-in-python)

Any other module where this works would be also okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're searching for [additionalProperties](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#additional-properties):

```yaml
type: object
properties:
  input:
    type: array
    items:
      type: string
  split_to:
    type: object
    additionalProperties:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
additionalProperties: false
```

Setting it to `false` disallows unknown properties in the root mapping. Since JSON Schema is for JSON, keys will always be strings and you can set only the value type for additional properties.

Comment: Thanks! Will look into it and see if this suits.